# Search results still shows, although the page does not exists

Tags: search-results

SharePoint 2010

We removed a page from SharePoint, but when people make search it appears as the first item.

I did the following and it still shows:

1. Did a full crawl
2. excluded the url and did a full crawl

Here are more details about the issue. The page was moved using **Content and structure** but for some reason in search it still refers to the old url and when users click on the link in search result they get 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would check and make sure you don't have any best best / promoted results configured.  If it's a natural search result - you may have to reset your index and then do a full crawl.

**EDIT**

You may be able to remove items directly. When you review your crawl logs do a search for this item via URL.  If you select the item in the log there is an action there to remove it from the index.

Comment: No best bet. The problem I cannot reset the index since we have other contents and that will take days to crawl.

Comment: I updated answer with another option - You may be able to exclude it directly

Comment: I will try this action